# How to take only first index from combobox c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have two indexes on my combobox.

I want to take only the first index ?

Can I get some example ?

The code:

```
              foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2["Station"].ToString() + " - " + dr2["Ime"].ToString());
            }
```

I want to take `dr2["Station"].ToString()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Win Forms `ComboBox` has both a `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedText` property.

Once your list is loaded with items you can pick which one is selected like this:

```
// selected by position in the list
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

// ... by value
comboBox1.SelectedText = "some value";
```