# How to get first item from comboxbox in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I fill one combobox with two columns from database with this code:

```
            foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt2.Rows)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2["Station"].ToString() + " - " + dr2["Ime"].ToString());
            }
            dbconn.Close();
```

and combobox look like this:

[image: filling combobox]

Now I want to take only first item from this combobox (the numbers) and put into my query for data from database.

I want variable **Stations** to be with first item from combobox.

I try to get the first index from combobox, but when I debug I see value on the variable is -1 everytime..

The code:

```
        var Stations = comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CALL aladin_surfex.Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram_cell('"+ dtnow +"', " + Stations + ", 5)", dbconn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        dbconn.Open();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dt = ds.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        dbconn.Close();
```

I upload a picture from debug mode:

[image: Stations every step = -1 ?]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take only first index from combobox c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938241/how-to-take-only-first-index-from-combobox-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't understand, didn't you already got the answer ? But if it is another question you should change the title and indicate that it is another subject, related to the previous question, as well as change the beginning of text that is here the same. Else it is like the same question with more details and a little variation.

Comment: Writing `var Stations = comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;` sets Stations to -1 as well as comboBox1.SelectedIndex to -1, so you have -1, indeed, everytime.

Comment: `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;` basically removes the selection. Is this intended?

Comment: @Mong Zhu Indeed. I don't think it is the goal here but the source of the problem.

Comment: And if `CALL` supports sql parameters, you should use them for security reasons, instead of string concatenation.

Comment: What's the use of this: `foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; }`. Did you check what it does?

Answer (score 1):

> I want variable Stations to be with first item from combobox

Instead of

```
var stations = comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

use

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
var stations = comboBox1.SelectedText; // or Text
```